# Slick Slider filter by class instead of :even

Tags: javascript, slick.js

This is a code from the slick slider to filter the divs. I couldn't find any solution online and also didn't manage it by myself to change ':even' to a class name.

This is the following code:

```
var filtered = false;

$('.js-filter').on('click', function(){
  if (filtered === false) {
    $('.filtering').slick('slickFilter',':even');
    $(this).text('Unfilter Slides');
    filtered = true;
  } else {
    $('.filtering').slick('slickUnfilter');
    $(this).text('Filter Slides');
    filtered = false;
  }
});
```

Is the part where it says ':even' changeable to a class name? I need the code exactly how it is except the ':even' part. Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Yes just simply replace the `:even` with the classname of the slick slider item. It's important that the slick slider items are direct children of your slider element for this to work. So for example:

```html
<div class="my-slick-slider">
  <div class="item dog"><!-- YOUR ELEMENT --></div>
  <div class="item dog"><!-- YOUR ELEMENT --></div>
  <div class="item cat"><!-- YOUR ELEMENT --></div>
  <div class="item cat"><!-- YOUR ELEMENT --></div>
</div>
```

Put the content of your slider items inside the item divs. Then you can filter by simply creating a javascript function that filters the slick slider by classname:

```js
const filterByClassname = (classname) => {
  $('.filtering').slick('slickUnfilter');
  $('.my-slick-slider').slick('slickFilter', `.${classname}`);
});

// filter by classname "cat"
filterByClassname("cat");
```

2 important things here:
 - notice that you have to prepend a dot befor the classname. The jquery function `filter` needs a css selector as input.
 - notice that with `.slick('slickUnfilter');` you can rreset the filtering of your slider. I would suggest to do that always befor applying a new filter.

Hope that helps! Heres a fully functioning codepen example with filtering applied: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/dcts/pen/bGGaMOg)

Answer (score 0):

Slick uses the official .filter jQuery method, and you can find the documentation here:

http://api.jquery.com/filter/

I'm pretty new to JS and like you, I wasn't able to just place a class in the selector spot of the method. I'm a little shaky on the rules still,  but I did make some progress by using:

```
    $('.filtering').slick('slickFilter','div:contains("test")');
```

I'm not sure what your HTML looks like, but mine is as follows (in PUG format):

```
//- Carousel
.slick-carousel
  div
    .item
      img(src="images/test1.jpg").item-trigger
      .item-modal
        .item-modal-content
          span.item-close-button ×
          name test
```

This sort of works, but it also nukes the whole carousel, buttons and everything. Haven't figured that part out yet but maybe this will set you on the right path

Comment: did you find something out by now? Im facing the same issue.

Comment: found a solution, see my answer! :)